# SQL: How to separate ordered rows into groups; split based on group-breaking row

Tags: sql, grouping

I have rows ordered by date that I need to split into separate groups based on a field that creates a "break" in the grouping. The breaking rows will be removed so they need to be in their own group. The answer probably exists somewhere but I can't find anything. I can do this with a loop but I'd prefer not to.

Example:

```
Date          BreakField    Group (this is the field I need)
2018-07-01    0             1
2018-07-02    0             1
2018-07-03    0             1
2018-07-04    1             0
2018-07-05    0             2
2018-07-06    0             2
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: What SQL have u tried so far?

Comment: please post expected output and add tag of the database system you are using

Comment: btw, search for gap and island problem ...

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use difference of `row_numbers` to define the group :

```
select Date, BreakField, (case when breakfield = 1 then 0 
                              else dense_rank() over (order by grp) 
                          end) as Group 
from (select *, row_number() over (order by date) -
                row_number() over (partition by breakfield order by date) as grp
      from table
     ) t
order by date;
```

Answer (score 1):

The very fact that a column in your table is named "breakfield" is a dead giveaway that you need to reconsider your problem starting from several steps before what you're telling here : it betrays that your thinking is procedural (meaning you have *invented* the column with the specific purpose of subsequently doing this row-by-row processing on it), when SQL thinking is supposed to be declarative, meaning it's supposed to do data processing in terms of attributes *that are meaningful to the business in their own right*.

That said, the value for your Group column appears like it can be computed as the scalar subquery

```
SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
  FROM <yourtable> AS INNER
 WHERE BreakField = 1 AND INNER.Date < OUTER.Date
```

to get

```
SELECT ...
       , (subquery>) AS group
  FROM <yourtable> AS OUTER
 WHERE ...
```

And *that* said, any hopes that the query optimizer will spot the occasion to do single-pass processing for this query are probably in vain, so it is most likely a better solution to resort to your specific DBMS's nonstandard features for achieving this (but for people to answer that here you'd have to specify which DBMS that is).

Answer (score 0):

If your using sql-server, you can use the 2 steps below:

> 1. Insert it into a temp table to have it an ordered id

```
SELECT
    [TempTable_ID] = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY [Date]),
    [Date],
    [BreakField],
    [Group]
INTO #TempTable
FROM
    yourTable
```

> 2. Use the temp table to get the row number by Group

```
SELECT 
    [Date], 
    [BreakField],
    [Group],
    [RowNumberByGroup] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                PARTITION BY (
                                    SELECT
                                        ISNULL(MIN([t2.TempTable_ID]), 1)
                                    FROM
                                        #TempTable t2
                                    WHERE
                                        t2.[BreakField] = 1
                                        AND  t2.[TempTable_ID] < t1.[TempTable_ID] ) 
                                ORDER BY (
                                    SELECT
                                        ISNULL(MIN(t2.[TempTable_ID]), 1)
                                    FROM
                                        #TempTable t2
                                    WHERE
                                        t2.[BreakField] = 1
                                        AND  t2.[TempTable_ID] < t1.[TempTable_ID] ))
FROM
    #TempTable t1
WHERE 
    [BreakField] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `0`s in groups, you can us a cumulative conditional sum -- adding up the number of breaks up to each point:

```
select t.*,
       (case when breakfield = 1 then 0
             else 1 + sum(breakfield) over (order by date)
        end) as group
from t;
```

Otherwise, Yogesh's solution is a good solution.